# Customize Joomla 3.x tag page

Tags: javascript, css, tags, joomla3.1

Can anyone know where to customize Joomla 3.x tag page ? I'm a newbie, and Joomla tag is also new ). Please tell me how can I do and where can I find the file to customize. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to customize the tags component front-end layout view, so you may proceed as follows (this procedure is faster then a step-by-step using create directories, etc.):

1. Copy the /components/com_tags "com_tags" directory into your /templates/your_template/html directory;
2. Check that you have now the following: /templates/your_template/html/com_tags;
3. Expand the /templates/your_template/html/com_tags/ directory and delete the directories "controllers", "helpers", "models" and the files "controller.php", "metadata.php", "router.php" and "tags.php";
4. Expand the remaining directory /templates/your_template/html/com_tags/views/;
5. Inside you have the "tag" and "tags" directories which each of them have a directory "tmpl";
6. Delete the files "view.feed.php" and "view.html.php" in each of them (leave the "index.html";
7. Now inside each of the "tmpl" directories, move the files (except the index.html and the xml files) to each of its parent directories ("tag" and "tags");
8. Delete the "tmpl" directories;
9. Now, you have, inside each "tag" and "tags" directories" the files you want/need to customize. Changing these files will override the components' main files.

You should have the structure in your template directory similar to the following:

```
/templates/
/your_template/
    /html/
        /com_tags/
            /tag/
                /* the files you will be able to override are here */
            /tags/
                /* the files you will be able to override are here */
```

Hope it helps. For further reference, visit the [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll do it and get back to tell you :)